# use move_uploaded_file more than once

Tags: php, file-upload

I call the move_uploaded_file on my code twice but seems that the second one doesn't work.

If I interchange the position of them,

then first one will works, but the second won't.

any suggestion?

Comment: Once the file has been moved I'm guessing it doesn't exist in the  original place anymore, try using copy on the new file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't move a file twice. Perhaps you are looking for `copy()`. When you move the file, the original doesn't exists anymore.

Docs: http://php.net/copy

You could use `move_uploaded_file` and copy the file from there again

Answer (score 3):

Form PHP manual: [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) — Moves an uploaded file to a new location

If I understand right, what you probably do is that when you first call `move_uploaded_file` function you move the uploaded file into a new location, then when you call `move_uploaded_file` function the second time the function does nothing because the file is moved already.

Answer (score 1):

[`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) as the name suggests, moves the temporary file. After it has been called, the temporary file no longer exists because it has moved.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

> If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, when you moved the file once, it's not there anymore, it's like when you move a file from one folder to another in your computer.

On the second "move" you could use `copy()` to copy the file:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.copy.php