# why move_uploaded_file not working in a for loop(for each time different folder location)?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload the single file in a for loop. Each time when the loop runs, the file location is different.

The below code is the one i tried,

```
$num =3;
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
        if (isset($_FILES['pic'])) {

            $tmpname = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
            $dir = $i . "/images";
            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777);
                $index_file = "<?php\nheader(\"Location: ../index.php\");\n?>";
                $fp = fopen($dir . "/index.php", "w");
                fwrite($fp, $index_file);
                fclose($fp);
            }
            $ext = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
            $filetype = pathinfo($ext, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $unique_name = (uniqid(rand(), true)) . "." . $filetype;

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $dir . "/" . $unique_name)) {
                $file = "images/" . $unique_name;
                echo "uploading";
                unlink($i . "/" . $customer["pic"]);
            } else {
                echo "not uploading";
            }
}
```

Comment: So you're doing what? Trying to move the same file three times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use move\_uploaded\_file more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491027/use-move-uploaded-file-more-than-once)

Comment: @mario you are saying that temporary file will be erased on the first time upload. Am i right?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes i need to upload the same file thrice on different location each time

Comment: If you move a file from A to B; you can't then move it again from A to C and from A to D, because it's no longer at A, it's at B because you moved it..... "move" means exactly that, move.....if you want 3 copies of that file (why?) then you need to move it once, and then ___copy___ it twice more

Comment: @MarkBaker how can i copy the file from one location to another

Comment: Incredibly, PHP has a function called [copy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Answer (score 0):

As there are multiple files to be uploaded, so each of it has a unique name.
You need to **replace** `$tmpname = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];` with

> `$tmpname = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'][$i];`

```
$num =3;
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
        if (isset($_FILES['pic'])) {

            $tmpname = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $dir = $i . "/images";
            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777);
                $index_file = "<?php\nheader(\"Location: ../index.php\");\n?>";
                $fp = fopen($dir . "/index.php", "w");
                fwrite($fp, $index_file);
                fclose($fp);
            }
            $ext = $_FILES['pic']['name'][$i];
            $filetype = pathinfo($ext, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $unique_name = (uniqid(rand(), true)) . "." . $filetype;

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $dir . "/" . $unique_name)) {
                $file = "images/" . $unique_name;
                echo "uploading";
                unlink($i . "/" . $customer["pic"]);
            } else {
                echo "not uploading";
            }
}
```

Comment: no the file and the file name should be the same but i need to upload it on 3 different location

Comment: So why you are using the complete code in `for loop` instead just use the `move_uploaded` function in for loop.

Comment: @ArunkumarPonnusamy, instead just use the move_uploaded function in for loop then